# Linq - How can a add the contents of two list

Tags: c#, linq

I have two `IEnumberable<double>` list.

How can i add the each value of one list to the value in the same position in the other list using Linq?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Enumerable.Zip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) to do this:

```
var results = first.Zip(second, (f,s) => f+s);
```

Note that, if the lists aren't the same length, your results will be the length of the shorter of the two lists (`Zip` as written above will add together elements until one sequence ends, then stop...)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming both are the same length, you can use [Zip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) and not lose anything.  If they are of different lengths, the shortest list length will be the resulting length.

```
first.Zip(second, (a,b) => a+b);
```

Comment: actually Zip will also work if they are not the same length. As Reed mentions above, the result will be the length of the shorter list

Answer (score 2):

with .NET 4 - you can use ZIP

```
var sumList = numbers2.Zip(numbers,
    (first, second) => first+second);
```

You can find a [.NET 3.5 implementation here](http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2008/11/03/c-4-0-feature-focus-part-3-intermezzo-linq-s-new-zip-operator.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to have your output contain all elements (or get a feel for what will be going on under the covers of Linq) you can roll your own overload of Zip like so:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Zip<T>(IEnumerable<T> first, IEnumerable<T> second, Func<T,T,T> aggregator)
{
    using (var firstEnumerator = first.GetEnumerator())
    using (var secondEnumerator = second.GetEnumerator())
    {
        var movedFirstButNotSecond = false;
        while ((movedFirstButNotSecond = firstEnumerator.MoveNext()) && secondEnumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            yield return aggregator(firstEnumerator.Current, secondEnumerator.Current);
            movedFirstButNotSecond = false;                
        }
        while (movedFirstButNotSecond || firstEnumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            yield return firstEnumerator.Current;
            movedFirstButNotSecond = false;
        }
        while (secondEnumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            yield return secondEnumerator.Current;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This Zip method isn't "correct". If you have a list of 10 items and a list of 9 items, your result will be a list of 9 items. If you have a list of 9 items and a list of 10 items, then your result is a list of 10 items. Not consistent.